# format y axis for plotting time of day with qplot/ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have many data entries with two properties, the time of day (24h format, UTC, no date given) and a string containing the type of data.

I want to visualize the distribution of entries along the time axis for each type.

Consider the following example code:

```
library(ggplot2)

time <- c("22:12", "11:04", "00:04", "23:45", "12:04", "16:33")
type <- c("Foo", "Bar", "Foo", "Foo", "Foo", "Bar")

data <- data.frame(time, type)

qplot(data$type, strptime(data$time, "%H:%M")) +
  scale_y_datetime(date_breaks="1 hour", date_labels="%H:%M") + xlab("Type") + ylab("Time")
```

I want the chart to display the type on the x axis and the y axis to be in the range from 00:00 to 23:59 (no matter what actual times are in the dataset).

Not only does the time ranges from 21.00 to 22.00 (*overflowing* once), but the single entries are also displayed wrong (just look at the two 'Bar' entries):

[image]

Do you have any idea why the axis labels are that strange, and why the time it not plotted at the correct position? Maybe a timezone issue?

Comment: If you take away the `scale_y_datetime`, I think it plots correctly (but now has the date shown too)

Comment: O try to change time variable format from factor to POSIXct.

Comment: timezone problem. scales:::date_format takes UTC by default

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `scales:::date_format` takes UTC by default and I cannot see how to change this argument through `scale_y_datetime`, the simplest solution is probably to specify that you are using UTC whatever your real timezone.

```
qplot(data$type, strptime(data$time, "%H:%M", tz = "UTC")) +
  scale_y_datetime(date_breaks="1 hour", date_labels="%H:%M", expand = c(0,0)) +
  xlab("Type") + ylab("Time")
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! Using your code the dots are shown properly, but the y axis is still displaying the wrong range( 23.00, 00.00, 01.00, ..., 23:00, 00:00). Do you have any idea how to fix  this as well?